# Join two textfiles on 1st column keeping order and unpairable lines from 1st file

Tags: text-processing, join, merge

I need to merge two files that I have but I first need it to match before merging them. 
This is my first file containing lets say 1 Million lines.

```
abcde
fghi
jklmn
opqrs
123456
0000
```

Second file contains 3 million lines but still some lines has the string that's in the first file.

```
543123:fdfdss
dfskld:533fg
abcde:1234
fdskls:fkdfs
gfdkls:flfds
0000:5432
fdsk:saakl
```

Output:

```
abcde:1234
fghi
jklmn
opqrs
123456
0000:5432
```

I want the output to be file1:file2 but only if it matches with the first column of file2 with the string in file1.
I don't want to scramble the sorting format I want it to be in this order and I want to keep the file1 strings but just add the matching strings.

Comment: @don_crissti I'm sorry I didn't explain it too well. I edited my post. I want to keep the order and keep file1 strings but just add the file2 matching strings to file1.

Answer (score 5):

The easy way is via `awk` - just read the 2nd file, save each line into an array (where the index is $1) and when reading 1st file check if the line is already an index in array - if so replace with the value of that element:

```
awk -F: 'NR==FNR{z[$1]=$0;next}
($0 in z) {$0=z[$1]};1' file2 file1
```

You can do this with `join` too but it requires more work (basically, numbering lines in 1st file so as to be able to sort the result of `join` and restore the order):

```
join -a 1 -t: -1 2 -2 1 <(nl -s: -ba -nrz file1 | sort -t: -k2,2) \
<(sort -t: -k1,1 file2) | sort -t: -k2,2 | cut -d: -f1,3-
```